# Trying to Create A Macro To Import Multiple CSV Files To Microsoft Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access-2016

Hi I am trying to Create A Macro To Import Multiple CSV Files To Microsoft Access. I get new raw sales data that I add to the folder I am importing from. The code works fine however whenever i rerun the macro to upload the new data, data already within access get duplicated. So how do I add code in my macro to ignore already imported data.

Also I was wondering if there is away to consolidate every weeks data into one query or table so that when i open it in excel it only shows one sheet containing all the data and not multiple sheets of each individual weeks sales data.

```
Public Function import_data_files()

    Dim report_path As String, file_name As String
    
    report_path = "C:\Users\omar-\OneDrive\Desktop\Work\WeeklySalesData-Raw\"
    
    file_name = Dir(report_path & "*.csv", vbDirectory)
    
    Do While file_name <> vbNullString
        DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , Trim(Replace(file_name, ".csv", "")), report_path & file_name, True
        
        file_name = Dir        
    Loop
    
    MsgBox "Data files imported.", vbInformation
    
End Function
```

Comment: You cant do what you want on a simple import. You will have to actually query into the CSV file so you can do a SQL SELECT and add a clause that will help you skip what you want to skip.

Comment: my code imports everything is there no way of adding a checker to see if the table is already in access to not reimport that data

Comment: everything? if you empty the table before the import, will that work?

Comment: i ended up making a function that checks each tables name. And then within my code for importing the csv files into table it first checks to see if the file name matches the table name. If false then procced and import else move on to the next